# Problem 4.20 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

> If $E$ is a nonempty subset of a metric space $X$, define the distance from $x \in X$ to $E$ by $$ \rho_E (x) = \inf_{z \in E} d(x, z). $$

> (a) Prove that $\rho_E (x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \overline{E}$.

> (b) Prove that $\rho_E$ is a uniformly continuous function on $X$, by showing that
> $$ \left\vert \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \right\vert \leq d(x, y) $$
> for all $x \in X$, $y \in X$.

**My attempt:**

**Part(a)** ($\Rightarrow$)
Suppose $\rho_E(x)=0= \rho_E(x) = \inf \left\{ \ d(x, z) \ \colon \ z \in E \ \right\}$, where $x \in X$. Assume to get contradiction, that $x\notin \overline E=E \cup E^\prime$. Which means $x \notin E$ and $x \notin E^\prime$. So, $\exists \epsilon \gt 0, \nexists x \neq y \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap E$. Which is same as saying, $B(x,\epsilon) \cap E= B_{E}(x,\epsilon) =\{z\in E|d(x,z) \lt \epsilon\}=\emptyset$. Thus, $0 \lt \epsilon \leq d(x,z), \forall z\in E$ implies $0 \lt \epsilon \leq \rho_E(x)$. Which contradicts our initial assumption of $\rho_E(x)$ being zero.

Conversely($\Leftarrow$), let $x\in \overline{E}$ i.e.  $x\in E$ or $x\in E^\prime$. If $x\in E$, then $d(x,z)=0$ for $z=x \in E$. In this case, $\rho_E(x)=0$. Now, if $x\in E^\prime$, then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists x \neq y \in B(x,\epsilon) \cap E$. So that $y \in E$ and $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$, $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$. Thus, $d(x,y) \lt \epsilon$,$\forall \epsilon \gt 0$. Take $\epsilon:=\frac{1}{n} \gt 0$ and $y_{\frac{1}{n}}=z_n \in E$. So we have constructed a sequence which convergence to $x$ i.e. $d(x,z_n) \rightarrow 0$. Thus, inf $d(x,z)=0=\rho_E(x)$.

**Part(b)**
$\rho_E(x) \leq d(x, z) \leq d(x, y) + d(y, z)$. Now take inf on right hand side to obtain $\rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) \leq d(x,y)$. Similarly we can show $\rho_E(y) - \rho_E(x) \leq d(x,y)$ also holds. So, $| \rho_E(x) - \rho_E(y) | \leq d(x,y)$.

**Is this proof correct and satisfactory?**

Comment: it written in a bit of a confusing manner with all the logical quantifiers. I would rephrase the negation of limit point slightly, which would be $$\exists\varepsilon>0:(B(x,\varepsilon)\setminus\{x\})\cap E=\emptyset$$ this is clearly equivalent to the negation of your definition of a limit point, but makes for a quicker proof. On the converse direction of part (a), first state clearly the definition of $x$ being a limit point of $E$. then obtain your sequence $z_n$ in $E$ with $d(x,z_n)<1/n$ for all $n$. no need to set epsilon to $1/n$ or use $y_{1/n}$. its confusing and nonstandard

Comment: nice job on part b.

Comment: Thanks for your review and suggestions.

Comment: OHHH.. that’s clever. By theorem 3.2(d) there exist some sequence in E which converge to x. We don’t have to constructing any sequence unnecessarily.

Comment: im not sure what that theorem says, but the point was that you have shown, by the characterization of the infimum in the reals, that $d(x,E)=0$, since for each $\varepsilon>0$, you have exhibited a number $d(x,y)$ such that $0\leq d(x,y)<0+\varepsilon$

Comment: Yeah. Theorem 3.2(d) - if x is a limit point of E then there exist some sequence in E which converge to x.